# Форматы даты в Django

Tags: python, django, дата, docxtpl

Создал форму и в ней поле с выбором даты рождения. Для создания формы использовал django-crispy-forms

```
date_born = forms.DateField(label='Дата рождения', widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d-%m-%Y', attrs={'type': 'date'}), required=False)
```

При заполнении поля, формат даты нормальный, виде дд.мм.гггг, когда же пытаюсь использовать данную переменную, чтобы вывести, то выводится в формате гггг.мм.дд. В settings.py прописывал формат даты, не ничего не менялось:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d.%m.%Y']
DATE_FORMAT = ['%d.%m.%Y']
```

Comment: Каким образом выводите

Comment: form.cleaned_data['date_born']

Comment: попробуйте добавить `date` функцию из django или шаблонный фильтр https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Comment: Не получится. Я вывожу не сразу в HTML, а создаю словарь, и уже по ключу вызываю значение. context = {'date_born':form.cleaned_data['date_born']}

Comment: фильтр - это обычная функция. никто не запрещает импортировать ее в нужном месте и использовать по назначению

Comment: а выводится у вас в формате YYYY-MM-DD потому что это "чистый" вид

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пытался изменить форматы даты на первоначальном этапе. В итоге просто изменил вывод даты с помощью strftime

```
date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

Эти данные у меня используются с библиотекой docxtpl, которая заполняет данные в .doc формате. И заметил, что если не заполнять поле дату, то файл не создаётся. Это из-за strftime.